# Firebase dynamicLinks: Do i need an app on the store for my link to work correctly?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I created a dynamic link on firebase dynamics like in their tutorial here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive
using an app ID (WhatsApp) which is not mine because not yet on App Store.

When i click on it (in Notes or Mail), it goes to Safari and ask if i want to open WhatsApp in AppStore. 
When i come back to my app, i don't receive any link.

Do i need to publish my app to the appstore before it works?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to publish your App in AppStore in order to test the Firebase Dynamic Links.

Did you followed steps here https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive regarding `Set up Firebase and the Dynamic Links SDK` and `Open Dynamic Links in your app`?
Is your App receiving any link in UIApplicationDelegate's `openURL:` method? Can you reproduce the issue with quick-start App https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/dynamiclinks ?

Comment: I was using iOS 11.1 ans dynamic link  was not working on it. After updating my phone to iOS 11.2 it is working now.
Thanks for your help

Comment: This behavior does not depends on iOS version. Maybe you switched Wifi->Cellular? Also, what is locale on your iPhone? Anyway, happy it works.